# nature of turning point of $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ at $0$

Tags: derivatives

The function $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ has limit $1$ at $0$. It has derivative defined everywhere except at the origin. At the origin, the derivative exists and it is $0$. The limit of the second derivative is positive, but it is not a minimum point. It is not a turning point.

Does that mean the function $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ is not differentiable at $0$?

Comment: Your function is not defined at 0, hence not differentiable at 0.

Comment: This is the generating function of the numbers of Bernoulli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're considering
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x}{e^x-1} & \text{if $x\ne0$}\\[6px]
1 & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
It is an everywhere continuous function.

The function is obviously differentiable for $x\ne0$, with
$$
f'(x)=\frac{e^x-1-xe^x}{(e^x-1)^2}
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x+x^2/2+o(x^2))-1-x(1+x+o(x))}{(x+o(x))^2}=
-\frac{1}{2}
$$
the function is also differentiable at $0$, by l’Hôpital’s theorem.

Comment: urgh, i calculated this limit wrong. thank you